# SSMS Graphical Bug?

Tags: ssms

When I open up SSMS it looks like this:
I've tried re-installing the program and downloading the latest .net and visual c++

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unchecking "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and "Use hardware graphics acceleration" under "Tools...Options...General"

Seems to work just fine to resolve the issue.

Why this is the case I do not know. I have a Nvidia 970 card on my PC.